# Why does this query throw this error in Python?

Tags: python, sql

Code(in Python):

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ALL_BOOKS WHERE SUBJECT=\'BIO\';")
```

Error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` from the query and try:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ALL_BOOKS WHERE SUBJECT='\BIO\'")
```

Comment: It was the semicolon actually. It wasn't needed there. Either ways, thanks.